# Can I create another column conditional to the value of another column in a SELECT statement of the view i'm building?

Tags: sql, sas

I'm trying to create a column with values conditional to a previous column in the SELECT statement. Fwiw, column 3 will result in strings from 'Case 01' to 'Case 02' and is also a CASE statement.

```
CREATE VIEW name AS(
  SELECT column1, column2, colum 3,

    CASE
      WHEN SUBSTRING(column3,1,6) = 'Case 01'   THEN ...
      WHEN SUBSTRING(column3,1,6) = 'Case 02'   THEN ...
      WHEN SUBSTRING(column3,1,6) = 'Case 03'   THEN ...

    END AS column4

  FROM random_table
```

Basically, column4 will be created based on column3 values. Is this possible since the VIEW is not 'built' yet?

Thanks

Comment: Depends. Is `Column 3` a column in `random_table` or is it, too, derived with some formula?

Comment: Derived with some formula.

Comment: You are already on the right track, Did you try your code? The only "downfall" with this is that the type for column 4 needs to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, in your example, `column3` is a column in a table, so it should be fine to use in subsequent expressions:

```
CREATE VIEW name AS
  SELECT column1, column2, column3,
         (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(column3, 1, 6) = 'Case 01' THEN ...
               WHEN SUBSTRING(column3, 1, 6) = 'Case 02' THEN ...
               WHEN SUBSTRING(column3, 1, 6) = 'Case 03' THEN ...
               . . .
          END) AS column4
  FROM random_table;
```

Note that the parentheses around the subquery are not necessary.

If you were assigning an alias to the column, then you can use the `calculated` keyword:

```
CREATE VIEW name AS
  SELECT column1, column2, column3 as col3,
         (CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(calculated col3, 1, 6) = 'Case 01' THEN ...
               WHEN SUBSTRING(calculated col3, 1, 6) = 'Case 02' THEN ...
               WHEN SUBSTRING(calculated col3, 1, 6) = 'Case 03' THEN ...
               . . .
          END) AS column4
  FROM random_table;
```

`calculated` is a `proc sql` extension.  I am not aware of any other database that supports it.

The alternative is to use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I get 

ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, FROM, GE, GET, GT, GTT, IN, IS, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, NOTIN, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, 
              ~=.

I used the exact syntax as in your post.

Comment: @wimz . . .  That is curious.  By any chance, does it work as `when calculated col3 like 'Case 01%'`?

Comment: Seems to work, thanks. Probably can't use the calculated extension inside the substring function is my guess.?!

Comment: @wimz . . . I wonder if would work with `substr()`.  Your use of `substring()` actually suggests a pass-thru.  The proc SQL syntax is `substring(calculated col3 from 1 for 6)`.  That might work.

Comment: There it is, just tested it. I was using the wrong syntax of substring as you said. Is there one of the two thats faster than the other or its similar speed?

Comment: @wimz . . . I have no idea.  You would need to test that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Select from your case statement:

```
CREATE VIEW name AS(
  select column1, column2, column3, column4, 
    case column4
      when ... then ...
    end as column5
  from
  (
  SELECT column1, column2, colum 3,

    CASE
      WHEN SUBSTRING(column3,1,6) = 'Case 01'   THEN ...
      WHEN SUBSTRING(column3,1,6) = 'Case 02'   THEN ...
      WHEN SUBSTRING(column3,1,6) = 'Case 03'   THEN ...

    END AS column4

  FROM random_table ) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you will need to nest:-

```
CREATE VIEW name AS(
Select column1, colum2, column 3, Case WHEN column3="Case 1" then... END as column 4  
from (
      SELECT column1, column2, CASE
      WHEN columnn2 = 'x' then 'Case 1 End as column2
      FROM random_table) aa
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `CROSS APPLY`

```
CREATE VIEW name AS
  SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
  FROM random_table t1
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CASE ... <expression depdending on column1, column2, column3> .. END column4 ) t2
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  CASE ... <expression depdending on column1,..column4> .. END column5) t3
```

Quick demo

```
WITH tbl1 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(3))tt(col1)
)
, tbl2 AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1),(2))tt(col1)
)
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col1, col2, col3
FROM tbl1 t1
FULL JOIN tbl2 t2 ON t1.col1=t2.col1
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT isnull(t1.col1,100) + isnull(t2.col1,100) col2
  ) tt
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT  col2*col2  col3
  ) ttt
```

Result

```
col1    col1    col2    col3
1   1   2   4
NULL    2   102 10404
3   NULL    103 10609
```

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` can remove rows if it does not match (INNER JOIN), 'OUTER APPLY' might be a better approach.

Comment: @Jaques I see no `JOIN` at OP. Otherwise yes, `OUTER APPLY` may be needed. Or you can `CROSS APPLY` to the table expression of the whole join.

Comment: @Jaques and more, CASE doesn't filter rows. But you should be carefull minding null values as you always do with `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: Please read this. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/ Depends what you have in your cross apply

Comment: @Jaques Please note, SELECT in my CROSS APPLY includes no WHERE clause, so it just can not filter anything. This way it is just a calculation tool.

Comment: Added quick demo with FULL JOIN, CROSS APPLY.

Comment: I understand. I made a comment for an unsuspecting reader. I didn't attack or wrong the answer, I said, `can remove` and `might be`. Users are very touchy about there answers. I've noted and saw everything you've done. Just remember, sometimes there are a lot of noobs reading this, and then don't understand why they do not get the expected results.